# How to increase the performance when using jQuery and jQuery UI draggable feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have made a custom slider using jQuery UI draggable. I have the draggable control restricted to the x axis. When the control is dragged I check for the position of the control.

Depending on the position, I call a function called selectCells.

This function selects a range of cells in a table and sets the html of the cells to an image.

So for example if the index is 1 then I want to select all the cells in the first row and the first column ( Only one cell). If the index is 2 then I want to select the cells in the first 2 rows and columns ( four cells will be selected) etc.

I skip the first row and column because I dont want to fill these cells

My selectCells function is as follows

```
function selectCells(index, bGoingRight) {
    if (bGoingRight) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
            $(container).find('#exponentTable tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td').slice(1, index + 1).html(block);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            $(container).find('#exponentTable tr:eq(' + i + ') td:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')').html(grayBlock);
            $(container).find('#exponentTable tr:eq(' +(index + 1) + ') td:eq(' + ( 13 - i) + ')').html(grayBlock);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, if the user slides the slider fast thensome rows and columns are skipped.

Comment: create a demo...  would likely help a lot to cache rows and cut down a lot of DOM searching

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the tip, How would I cache the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As charlietfl said, once I cached the rows it increased performance.